# Perforce swarm - project job filter not working as expected

Tags: perforce

I'm trying to run an build-deploy-test pipeline on each perforce swarm review. 
Key point is: **pipeline should be optional**, i.e. the review requester should decide if the pipeline is to run.

My implementation is:

1. Created P4 Swarm project
2. Added some branch(to monitor specific depo `//some/depo/path`)
3. Added job filter: As far as I understand this feature, **only if this job is mentioned swarm project should trigger the pipelin**
4. Configured Jenkins job url in 'Automated tests' field
5. See image below

The result is:

1. When one requests review in the `//some/depo/path` regardless on whether the job was mentioned - which fails to deliver the key point above

**Any suggestions?**

[image: project settings screenshot]